# Command errored out with exit status 1 and access denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Recently I installed anaconda. Now, I uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled python 3.6. I am not a able to install some packages because of the following error.

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-4.0.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' 'c
:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip' insta
ll --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-b
uild-env-nt65tuv0\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-b
inary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (14 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", li
ne 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", li
ne 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
\pip\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 5, in <module>
      import locale
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\locale.py", l
ine 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\re.py", line
142, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\prog
rams\python\python36\python.exe' 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\py
thon36\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\
Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nt65tuv0\overlay' --no-warn-script-l
ocation --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 's
etuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\contextlib2.py", line 468, in __exit__
    if cb(*exc_details):
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\contextlib2.py", line 396, in _exit_wrapper
    return cm_exit(cm, *exc_details)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 175, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 199, in cleanup
    rmtree(ensure_text(self._path))
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 139, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 488, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 383, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 381, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local
\\Temp\\pip-install-k22kzs5t\\pyinstaller\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\Windows-32bi
t\\run.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line
 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line
 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__m
ain__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 75, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 121, in main
    return self._main(args)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\contextlib.py",
 line 89, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\cli\command_context.py", line 28, in main_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\contextlib2.py", line 479, in __exit__
    _reraise_with_existing_context(exc_details)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\contextlib2.py", line 340, in _reraise_with_existing_context
    raise exc_details[1]
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\contextlib.py",
 line 100, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 85, in tempdir_registry
    yield _tempdir_registry
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\contextlib2.py", line 468, in __exit__
    if cb(*exc_details):
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\contextlib2.py", line 396, in _exit_wrapper
    return cm_exit(cm, *exc_details)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\contextlib.py",
 line 89, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 46, in global_tempdir_manager
    _tempdir_manager = old_tempdir_manager
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\contextlib2.py", line 479, in __exit__
    _reraise_with_existing_context(exc_details)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\contextlib2.py", line 340, in _reraise_with_existing_context
    raise exc_details[1]
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\contextlib2.py", line 468, in __exit__
    if cb(*exc_details):
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\contextlib2.py", line 396, in _exit_wrapper
    return cm_exit(cm, *exc_details)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 175, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 199, in cleanup
    rmtree(ensure_text(self._path))
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\p
ip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 139, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 488, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 383, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", lin
e 381, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local
\\Temp\\pip-install-k22kzs5t\\pyinstaller\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\Windows-32bi
t\\run.exe'
```

This has been frustrating. I ran cmd with administrator too but other post aren't working for me. btw I have windows 7

Answer (score 0):

The error message - "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '... Windows-32bit\run.exe'" suggests that a 32-bit version file is being run, and hence is being denied access.

The problem may get solved by removing the existing version of Python from Windows and then installing the 64-bit version afresh.

**Tip for successful installation and hassle-free upgrade:**

Manually create the installation directory with small path, without spaces and with 'write' permissions for installing python, instead of the default one offered by the installer.

The installer installs to C:\users\name\app data\ ......
This path usually causes problems while upgrading Python.

**Tip:**

Create a folder named **C:\python3** (for installing python v3) and give 'write' permission to it to the user.

Select **C:\python3** as the installation directory during the installation.

This will help install python and also upgrade it without hassles in the future.

Comment: Ok. I will try that, and what about the first error?

Comment: Maybe the old version I installed before was 32 bit?

Comment: Yes. The older version could have been 32 bit one, which worked earlier. But, as mentioned, there has been a time lag of 2 years between the previous installation and now. The combination of windows updates and Python updates that have come in the past 2 years could have led to the error found. Removing all old installations and re-installing the latest 64-bit python can fix the problem.

Comment: Reinstalled python 3.6. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced the error, I closed cmd.
I started cmd with administrator and fired the command `nvm use 12.10.0` and it worked for me.